# String Format .format to variable

Tags: python, string, while-loop, iteration, string.format

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to pass in a string into an age variable using a while loop. This is the simplified version of the code using the .format string.  The following code works as expected.

```
num = 1
while num<7:
    age = 'My age is {}'.format(num)
    print(age)
    num+=2
```

The output is as shown below:

```
My age is 1
My age is 3
My age is 5
```

However, when I attempt to capture the string 'My age is {}' in the age variable using the while loop it doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
num = 1
age = 'My age is {}'
while num<7:
    age = age.format(num)
    print(age)
    num+=2
```

I get the following output.

```
My age is 1
My age is 1
My age is 1
```

Any idea the reason the num does not increment in the while loop in the second example?  What's the solution?

Comment: You are overwriting the `age` variable, and after the first loop, this variable doesnt have anymore the required `{}`

Comment: You cant override age.  Assign the return to a different variable and use that.  Tada~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overwriting the `age` string so there's nothing left to format in the second iteration. You could use two strings - one with the template to format in to, and one with the formatted result:

```
num = 1
template = 'My age is {}'
while num<7:
    age = template.format(num)
    print(age)
    num+=2
```

Answer (score 3):

The first time through the loop, you've replaced the `{}` in the string with a number. From that point forward, `format` doesn't have anything to do since the string doesn't have any formatting markers in it.